# Variable scope for a variable used in multiple userforms

Tags: vba, module, scope, userform

I am trying to figure out how scope works.

For instance: I'm working on a userform in which a check procedure validates that new entries are not already present in the list. Because I'm probably going to use the full name (concatenation of first and last name) in different userforms within the same worksheet, I entered it as a Global variable in the general module:

```vb
Public Sub PublicVars()

    Public FullName As String

End Sub
```

When I add the definition of the variable to the public sub, the check box does not work, but when I define it in the object in the userform, it does.

```vb
Private Sub cmbLastName_AfterUpdate()

    FullName = cmbFirstName & " " & cmbLastName

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("List_Full_Name"), FullName) Then
        FullNameError = MsgBox("Name already included in contact list. Edit contact?", vbYesNo, "Error")
    Else
   
    End If

End Sub
```

This seems sensitive to mistakes, as when I want to use FullName for another object in the same userform or in a different userform in the same workbook, I would have to redefine it locally. I am probably overlooking something, as I cannot believe this is the right/most effective way.

Are there any other ways to tackle this?

Comment: You could do worse than read this http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Scope.aspx